# Input string was not in a correct format. Error int FTP but in localhost codes is work

Tags: .net

My code is

```
   #region LikeExceli
   DynamicData dd = new DynamicData();
   dd.GerceklesenIMP = Convert.ToInt32(item["Impressions?"].ToString().Replace(",", ""));
   dd.GerceklesenClick = Convert.ToInt32(item["Clicks?"].ToString().Replace(",", ""));
   dd.CampaignName = item["Campaign?"].ToString();
   dd.AdvertName = item["Advert Name"].ToString();
   dd.GercekHarcamaUSD = fr.ConvertMoney(item["Spent?"].ToString());
   dd.Likes = Convert.ToInt32(item["Page likes?"].ToString().Replace(",", ""));
   dd.FK_Campaign = kampanyaid;
   dd.CPMUSD = Convert.ToDouble(item["CPM?"].ToString().Replace(".", ","));
   dd.CPCUSD = Convert.ToDouble(item["CPC?"].ToString().Replace(".", ","));
   dd.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
   #endregion
```

and my error is: `Input string was not in a correct format.`

But my codes working in localhost without any problem. When I uploaded the server, I got this error.

note: i'm import an excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly because your local machine is in a culture where the decimal separator is a comma instead of a period, so "one and a half" would be "1,5" instead of "1.5." Presumably your server *isn't* in such a culture.

You shouldn't be doing all this replacement anyway - parsing the values as a string really isn't a good idea. I strongly suspect that casting would work instead (although it's hard to say for sure, as we don't know what `item` is):

```
dd.CPMUSD = (double) item["CPM?"];
```

etc. Avoid string conversions where you can - and if you *have* to do a string conversion, try to avoid manually replacing bits of the string. So if you *really* have to use string parsing, use something like:

```
dd.CPMUSD = double.Parse(item["CPM?"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The invariant culture always uses a period as the decimal separator, which it sounds like your input does too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i'm fix my server regional settings and problem is solved. And sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: @user1939355: No, don't just change your server's regional settings - change your code so that it doesn't *depend* on the regional settings. Did you try the cast instead? It's a much cleaner solution than converting to a string and back.